# How to manage argument pattern, keys (and subways ?)

Tags: pgfkeys

I have two methods to draw an arrow on a segment but I would like to find a third more explicit one.

```
1) \draw[arrow scale=3,pos=.75,arrow=Stealth] (A) -- (B);
2) \draw[new arrow={.3}{3}{To}](A)-- (B);
```

With the last one if "To" is more or less explicit, it's not the case for .3 and 3. With the first one there are confusions. For example I need to use "arrow scale" because "scale" is used.
The idea is  to get a mix, something like `\draw[arrow={[type = Latex,pos=.5,scale=2]}]` with the possibility to default values. But I don't know how to do this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{ arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
  
 \tikzset{arrow/.default            = Triangle, 
          pos/.store in             = \apos, 
          pos                       = .5,
          arrow scale/.store in     = \ascale,
          arrow scale               = 1, 
          arrow/.style              = {decoration = {markings, 
                                               mark=at position \apos with {\arrow[scale=\ascale]{#1}}
                                              },
                                      postaction = {decorate}
                                 }
          }
        
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (2,1) ;
\coordinate (B) at  (6,3);
\draw[arrow scale=3,pos=.75,arrow=Stealth] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (2,1) ;
\coordinate (B) at  (6,3);
\tikzset{new arrow/.style n args={3}{decoration={markings,
                                     mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[scale=#2]{#3}}},
                                     postaction={decorate}
                                     }
}

\draw[new arrow={.3}{3}{To}](A)-- (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A note to case one: option `pos` is already defined and used by `tikz` hence one has to choose another name.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Doesn't it depend on the path? Here I know that's `scale `is not acceptable but I didn't have a problem with `pos`. Thanks for your answer, I learned many things.

Comment: The full path for the already-defined one is `/tikz/pos` (see sec. 17.8 "Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly", pgfmanual v3.1.9a), so `\tikzset{pos/.store in= \apos}` does redefine `pos` and will break, for example `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) node[pos=.5] {x};` (expected: node at midway, actual: node at path end). If in actual code some different default path is used, then it's all fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Syntax:

```tex
on path arrow=<arrow end tip>
on path arrow=<arrow end tip> at <pos>
on path arrow={<arrow end tip>[<arrow options>] at <pos>}
```

in which the `<pos>` is 0.5 by default.

Example usages:

```tex
\draw[on path arrow=Stealth] (A) -- (B);
\draw[on path arrow={To[scale=3] at .3}] (A)-- (B);
\draw[on path arrow={Latex[scale=5,blue] at .8}] (A)-- (B);
```

Implementation and full example:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  on path arrow/.code=%
  {%
    \pgfutil@in@{ at }{#1}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@
      \mytikz@parsearrow#1\mytikz@stop
    \else
      \mytikz@parsearrow#1 at .5\mytikz@stop
    \fi
  }
}

\def\mytikz@parsearrow#1 at #2\mytikz@stop{%
  % \pgferror{"\detokenize{#1}", "\detokenize{#2}"} % debug info
  \pgfutil@in@{[}{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@
    \mytikz@parsearrow@opt{#2}#1\mytikz@stop
  \else
    \mytikz@parsearrow@opt{#2}#1[]\mytikz@stop
  \fi
}

% #1 = pos, #2 = arrow end tip, #3 = arrow options
\def\mytikz@parsearrow@opt#1#2[#3]\mytikz@stop{%
  \pgfkeysalso{decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[#3]{#2}}
    },
    postaction={decorate}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (2,1);
  \coordinate (B) at (6,3);
  \draw[on path arrow=Stealth] (A) -- (B);
  \draw[on path arrow={To[scale=3] at .3}] (A)-- (B);
  \draw[on path arrow={Latex[scale=5,blue] at .8}] (A)-- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I referenced the implementation of key `/pgf/decoration/mark` in [`pgflibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex).

Similarly `on path reversed arrow` can be defined which will finally use `\arrowreversed` instead of `\arrow`. With some more effort it would be possible to use `on path arrow` multiple times on a path.

Comment: Thanks  Very useful ! You got your hands dirty !! I never thought I'd go so far. I've been going around in circles reading and re-reading the pgfmanual section about pgfkeys. Do you think it is possible to find a solution using the `argument pattern`?

Comment: @AlainMatthes If the pattern of accepted value has any optional parts, for example the `at <pos>` and `[<arrow options>]` parts in my answer, then it's impossible and a naive parser has to be written.

Comment: I have one question :  It would be interesting to have a default arrow type `\draw[on path arrow] (A) -- (B);`  how to do this ?

Comment: `on path arrow/.default=To`

Comment: What is the role of `\ pgfkeysalso` in your code ?

Comment: Another way to express "optional" is to provide multiple options among which some have their initial values (hence optional), similar to your case one. For example `arrow pos/.initial=.5, arrow options/.style={scale=3}` and then `mark=at position \pgfkeysvalueof{tikz/arrow pos} with {\arrow[arrow options]{...}}`. (`pgfkeys` does `\edef` to each key so it's valid to use expandable code in key name.)

Comment: `key/.code=\pgfkeysalso{#1}` is the same as `key/.style={#1}`. Actually it's how handler `/.style` is defined. Using `key/.code={<code 1> \pgfkeysalso{<options>} <code 2>}` one can control when should the `<options>` be executed (using the current default path, which is `/tikz` in `\tikzset`, `/` in `\pgfkeys`, and configurable by `/.cd`).